# Scaled sines equation: $ C \cos(Ax) = \cos(x) $

Tags: trigonometry

$$
C \cos(Ax) = \cos(x)
$$

$C, A, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there a known solution (for $x$)? If not, how could one approach it? [WA struggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3wAQ.png).

I thought of solving it for $C$ for each $x$ and for some $A_0$, then for another $A_1$ and seeing if it can generalize. Arrcosining until a full period is tiled seems to be a piecewise nightmare.

My goal is its inequality, which can be derived from the equality by solving periodicity, so if the inequality is somehow easier then that's also welcome.

Comment: This Eq, cannot be solved by hand, it can be sone nymerically or graphically by fixing the valies of $a,b,c$.

Comment: @ZAhmed I don't think that's true. A closed form expression should be obtainable with standard operators from periodicity and phase considerations.

Comment: In general for each $(a,b,C)$ will be an infinity of non-periodic solutions. For some very special cases it is possible to write the solutions in a nice form. But in general one would need to use numeric approximations.

Comment: @jjagmath Can this be shown? Periodic solutions can't be ruled out from non-periodicity of the sum of sines, e.g. $\cos(ax) = \cos(bx)$ has a closed-form periodic solution.

Comment: You should try the transformation $bx=y\implies x=\frac yb$ and rename $\frac ab= r$

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon That's one of the special cases I was talking in my comment. I don't know if it can be proved that in general the solutions are not periodic.

Comment: @jjagmath The $A \in \mathbb{Z}$ case is also of interest. Does that appear much more tractable? I can ask separately

Answer (score 1):

For the case where $A\in \Bbb Z$, one can use the [Tchebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n(x)$ to write the equation as $$C\; T_A(\cos x) = \cos x$$ which is a polynomial equation of degree $A$ in $\cos x$.

It's now clear that in general won't be a closed form for $A\ge 5$, but if some roots can be obtained, then the solutions to the original equation can be obtained from $\cos x = \alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are the roots of the polynomial (Since you are interested only in real solutions, you obviously discard the roots with absolute value greater than $1$).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure this proves no closed forms for $A \geq 5$, it just proves the formulation via Tchebyshev doesn't have it. $T$'s argument is $\cos(x)$ which is another infinite sum, it's possible some simplifying happens. I'd find it really strange for the solvability of this equation to break down past some integer frequency ratio. Regardless it's a good insight, +1

Comment: To clarify since it's a bit ambiguous, by "closed form" I do count infinite sums, and special functions that have a known Fourier transform. [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83315/50076) is my context, and here's an [acceptable example](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83321/50076).

Comment: If you're willing to accept infinite sums then you can consider the function $f(x) = C \cos(Ax)- \cos(x)$ and apply the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to obtain $f^{-1}$ and then evaluate $f^{-1}(0)$. That'll give you a series converging to one of the solutions.

Comment: The expression for $g_n$ comes to involve sincs, which is very likely to be in the solution I seek. It'll take some work to see if the math is really tractable but it appears to go in the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

First try $x=\tan^{-1}(y)$

$$c \cos(a \tan^{-1}(y))=\frac1{\sqrt{y^2+1}}$$

Then expand into a power function equation:

$$1/2 c ((1 - i y)^a + (1 + i y)^a) (y^2+1)^{-\frac a2}=\frac 1{\sqrt{y^2+1}} \iff((1 - i y)^a + (1 + i y)^a) (y^2+1)^\frac {1-a}2=\frac2c$$

Now we need the inverse of $((1 - i y)^a + (1 + i y)^a) (y^2+1)^\frac {1-a}2$. If $a\in\Bbb N$, then you expand the equation. There are a few ways to invert a general polynomial, but they require the [Riemann theta](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeierstrassEta2.html) or other functions. Alternatively, let’s use [root notation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Root/):

$$x=\tan^{-1}\left(\text{Root}\left[\frac c2((1 - i y)^a + (1 + i y)^a) (y^2+1)^\frac {1-a}2-1,1\right]\right)$$

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The roots expression looks like it can be simplified, but not sure - I'll try later. By "general polynomial" do you mean $A \in \mathbb{R}$? Also so I understand the last equation, we take $\tan^{-1}$ of $A$ roots of $y$? Then this answer seems to agree with @jjagmath's in that an $A$-th degree polynomial needs solving.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon By general polynomial I mean $a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+ a_1 x+a_0,n\in\Bbb N$ and coefficients $a_k$. From the  “root notation” link, Root$[f(x),1]$ means the smallest solution $x$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @jjagmath Since we have an explicit formula for the polynomial to solve.